# The closed-form expression for $C_n$ sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Suppose the following linear recurrence sequence
$$
C_n:=C_{n-2}+C_{n-4}+C_{n-6}\, .
$$ 
With the initial values 
$$
C_0=0 \, , \, C_1=1 \, , \, C_2=0 \, , \, C_3=0 \, , \, C_4=1 \, , \, C_5=1 \, , \, C_6=1 \, .
$$
It can be proved that another form of the $C_n$ sequence is as follows 
\begin{equation}
C_n:=\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
C_{n-3}+C_{n-1} &\mbox{if}& n=1~\mbox{mod}~2,\\
\\
C_{n-3}+C_{n-2} & \mbox{if}&n=0~\mbox{mod}~2.
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

With boundary conditions
$$
C_0=0 \, , \, C_1=1 \, , \, C_2=0 \, .
$$

We can proof that the generating function of $C_n$ sequence is in the following form

$$
C(x)=\frac{x-x^3+x^4}{1-x^2-x^4-x^6}\, .
$$

In addition, I found the combinatorial forms of even and odd terms of $C_n$ sequence. For even terms, we have

$$
C_{2n}=\sum_{(k_1,k_2,k_3)} 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
k_1+k_2+k_3 \\
k_1,k_2 , k_3
\end{array}
\right)
$$
where the summation is over non-negative integers satisfying
$$
k_1+2\, k_2+3\, k_3=n-1 \, .
$$
and for odd terms, the following relation is obtained 
$$
C_{2n+1}=\sum_{(k_1,k_2,\cdots,k_p)} \frac{k_2+k_3}{k_1+k_2+k_3}\times
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
k_1+k_2+k_3 \\
k_1,k_2 , k_3
\end{array}
\right)
$$
where the summation is over non-negative integers satisfying
$$
k_1+2\, k_2+3\, k_3+=n \, .
$$
My question is that how to find a closed-form expression for $C_n$ sequence, based on the parameter $n$. 
I used the auxiliary equation method to find closed-form expression for $C_n$ sequence but the auxiliary equation 
of $C_n$ sequence have complex roots and it's closed-form expression is complicated.

Is there a analytical method that we can get a closed-form expression for $C_n$ sequence. I would greatly appreciate for any suggestions.

EDIT: I claimed that the closed-form expression of the $C_n$ sequence ,by using auxiliary equation method, is complicated. I want to 
show it's complexity. In fact, we want to say why I want to find a closed-form expression with less  complexity. 
The auxiliary equation of the $C_n$ sequence is as follows
$$
x^6-x^4-x^2-1=0~.
$$
The roots of the above equation are
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
x_1&=1.356203066~,&\\
x_2&=-1.356203066~,&\\
x_3&=0.3985657592&+ \hspace{3mm} 0.7605905878\,i~,\\
x_4&=0.3985657592&- \hspace{3mm} 0.7605905878\,i~,\\
x_5&=-0.3985657592&+ \hspace{3mm} 0.7605905878\,i~,\\
x_6&=-0.3985657592&- \hspace{3mm} 0.7605905878\,i~.\\
\end{array}
\right.$$
Using the Demorgan's law about complex number
$$Z=x+\,i y \Leftrightarrow Z=r(\cos(\theta)+\,i \sin(\theta))$$
and based on initial values of the $C_n$ sequence that is defined at the first, the following 
closed-form expression for the $C_n$ sequence is obtained
\begin{eqnarray}\nonumber
C_n&=&0.1954392117(1.356203066)^n-0.01263567906(-1.356203066)^n \\  \nonumber
&&+{0.8586924398}^n(0.2878832995\cos(1.088116773n) \\  \nonumber
&&\hspace{32mm}- 0.06742448463\sin(1.088116773n) \\  \nonumber
&&\hspace{32mm}-0.4706868334\cos(2.053475881n) \\  \nonumber
&&\hspace{32mm}+0.6136685762\sin(2.053475881n))~.
\end{eqnarray}
In my research, the above closed-form is not applicable, just because of this, I asked this question.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to get a closed form for a sequence with
a rational generating function is to perform a partial fraction
decomposition of the generating function, either completely or in
this case in terms of $x^2$, and then recast the individual terms 
by substituting their geometric series. (The associated formulas
are generalized Binet formulas). So the result will most likely
be the same as the one you already indicated, but complex terms
in that expression are probably unavoidable, because
$1-t-t^2-t^3$, where $t=x^2$,  does have two complex roots.

Of course you can also compute the first 10 or 20 terms and
start from http://oeis.org/A213816 .

Comment: My attitude to the $C_n$ sequence is different from $A213816$ . Please notice that to selection of initial values.

Comment: @Amin235: It’s the same sequence with a different offset. The are related by $a_n=C_{n+3}$. (The OEIS sequence is indexed starting at $a_1$.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott you right but I said just my attitude to the $C_n$ sequence is different from $A213816$. I think, it is not important that the sequence is  $a_n$ or $C_n$. It is important that how to find a closed-form expression for $a_n$ or $C_n$ sequence, Thank you.